# React removing all entries from a state array rather than one with filter()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, state

SO as the title states im running into an issue with my react code that whenever i try and remove an item from the array it clears the state entirely (back to [])

My current code looks like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";

// Berries Container
export function Berries({
  filterOptions,
  selectedBerries,
  setSelectedBerries,
}) {
  // set our active berry, this is just for css styling to allow the berry to be toggled on or off
  const [activeBerry, setActiveBerry] = useState(false);

  let berries = [];

  const deleteItem = (name) => {
    setSelectedBerries((selectedBerries) =>
      selectedBerries.filter((item) => item.name === name)
    );
  };

  function handleActiveBerry(e) {
    // toggles the berry on or off
    setActiveBerry((activeBerry) => !activeBerry);
    if (!activeBerry) {
      setSelectedBerries([...selectedBerries, e]);
    }
    if (activeBerry) {
      deleteItem(filterOptions.name);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="filter-berries-item">
      <ul className={!activeBerry ? "berries" : "berries-activated"}>
        <img
          value={filterOptions.name}
          onClick={() => handleActiveBerry(filterOptions.name)}
          src={filterOptions.image}
          width={20}
          height={20}
        />
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The filter options is an object that is passed in and right now im trying to get the name property to append to the list when the item is clicked (toggled to true) and removed when it's clicked again (toggled to false)

So far I have tried a few options, including using the deleteItem function created above. This was suggested in another, yet similar question and did not work.

Edit1: I have also tried `selectedBerries.filter((item) => item.name === name))` and it just does not remove an entry at all

Edit 2:

The filterOptions is pretty much an object structured like so

```
export const testFilter = {
  berries: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "belue",
      get image() {
        return belue;
      },
    },
}
```

And passed down through props. I then get the name and add it as the arg for handle active berry and delete item

Comment: `selectedBerries.filter((item) => item.name === name)`  This removes everything except for the matching elements.  Sounds like this part might be backwards, did you try item.name !== name ?

Comment: Hi james yes, i did actually and will update the question my bad, when doing selectedBerries.filter((item) => item.name === name) it actually just didn't remove the entries at all.

Comment: @ShaAnder: If `.filter()` isn't producing the result you expect, what specific debugging observations do you make?  What is the value of `name` and what are each of the `item.name` values?  Which ones do you expect to be equal to one another?

Comment: originally i didn't use filter, I tried creating an empty array (which you can see there with ```let berries = []``` to push and pop items in and out and still had no such luck. 

In terms of the data it's actually an object structured like this (ill post an edit so it can be properly formatted. Considering im passing the filterOptions.name (which should be just the berry name as a string in I was expecting that having item.name !== name would read that if it found an entry it would delete it not the entire state.

Comment: In setSelectedBerry you should not expect the call to setActiveBerry to update the value of activeBerry right away.

Comment: And in terms of observations, what i can only assume is happening, is that while it's populating the field with the item name that I want, when i try and delete it it's searching for all the names in the filter options? and deleting them all? 

Im honestly not sure for the most part and that's why im here seeking a second set of eyes.

Comment: @ShaAnder: *"The filterOptions is pretty much an object structured like so"* - That object has no `name` property, so `filterOptions.name` would be `undefined`.  That object has a property which is an array which has objects that contain a `name` property, did you mean to use that instead?  It's important that you make *specific* debugging observations and test *specific* operations in the code, don't just vaguely indicate that code and/or data "is kind of like this" and "doesn't work".  If you're not familiar with debugging your code, now is the time to start.

Comment: @ShaAnder: *"what i can only assume is happening..."* - Don't assume.  Test.  Use your browser's debugging tools, output useful information to the console, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my question. Needed to use a change of syntax and args on the callback function.

Originally I tried to do it like this filtering the berries by selections and wrong syntax with no return. But after trying to convert it to a set and realizing I need to correct my syntax..

```
  const deleteItem = (name) => {
    setSelectedBerries((selectedBerries) =>
      selectedBerries.filter((item) => item.name === name)
    );
  };
```

I changed it from that to this:

```
  const deleteBerries = (berryName) => {
    setSelectedBerries((selectedBerries) =>
      selectedBerries.filter((selectedName) => {
        return selectedName !== berryName;
      })
    );
  };
```